# 'abstract' slab/arena memory management/allocation library

Tags: library, software-development, c++, c, memory-management

I'm interested in a library for managing allocation and de-allocation of memory within an abstract slab. That is, a library which doesn't use `malloc()`/`operator new`/`sbrk`, but initially gets a contiguous range of addresses (maybe I've malloc()ed for it, or maybe it's managing space on some remote device), but takes allocation and de-allocation requests and returns regions within the slab. The memory managing code does also not access the memory it manages; it doesn't know what that memory is, so it can't do things like write to it, or move parts of it elsewhere etc.

Requirements:

- Gratis
- Free and Open Source
- Has some documentation
- Note that the allocation mechanism cannot use the slab/arena to store any state (counters, pointers etc.); it can use the default allocator (e.g. malloc()/new) or some other mechanism for that.

Preferences:

- C or C++ bindings
- Written in modern C++
- Supports prospective/time-based allocation ("I need X bytes between abstract time point t_1 and abstract time point t_2"; this allows for over-allocation over all time units, as long as there is no over-allocation at an individual time unit.)
- Supports specifying alignment requirements
- Supports resizing better than allocating a new segment and deallocating the old one
- Actively maintained

Answer (score 0):

Take look at the [boost pool](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_63_0/libs/pool/doc/html/index.html) library which is a C++ library which has most of the features you are looking for. It is part of the [boost](http://www.boost.org/) library which is open source, well maintained and tested portable library.

In the [detailed documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_63_0/libs/pool/doc/html/boost_pool/pool/pooling.html) about pool it dives into how memory segmentation and allocation is handled. It is very well documented with extensive test cases.

Comment: Looking at the documentation for that, it seems boost pool _does_ use the slab/arena to store state - so this does not fit my criteria. I've edited to make that clearer.